# How to validate for illegal fields in Model Validation

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a .NET Core 2.2 web-api that accepts a PersonDto, it is getting validated with Model Validation, but it does not check for illegal fields. It only checks if matching fields are valid.

I want to make sure that the supplied JSON contains only the fields that are in my Dto (Class).

```
public class PersonDto
  {
    public string firstname { get; set; }
    public string lastname { get; set; }
  }
```

My controller looks simplified like this:

```
public async  Task<ActionResult<Person>> Post([FromBody] PersonDto personDto)
{
    // do things
}
```

I send it incorrect fields (name does not exist in my dto) and the ModelState is valid.

```
{
  "name": "Diego"
}
```

I expected the Model Validation to complain that the field "Name" does not exist.

How can I check for illegal fields?

Comment: Why would you wanted to check for unknown fields, why can't you just ignore them?

Comment: To protect the calling client from making mistakes.

Comment: You should use ModelState for that

Comment: How do you propose to check for illegal field? Have you seen the answer of Xing? It added the illegal fields to the modelstate error collection. Is there a better way?

Comment: As i said before, there is no need to protect the client for making mistakes. Let's say you have a model which has requires a name and age, if you pass those values and   also height ModelState.IsValid returns true and ignores the height. But if you just pass name and height ModelState.IsValid returns false. So I don't see why you would want to do a extra filter. The only thing you add is extra complicity and reduce performance. Just my 2cents tho.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `ActionFilter` and `Reflection` to compare the request body content to the model fields. If there are unexpected fields, manually add model errors and the `ModelState.IsValid` will be false.

1.Create an ActionFilter

```
public class CompareFieldsActionFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    { 
        //get all fields name
        var listOfFieldNames = typeof(PersonDto).GetProperties().Select(f => f.Name).ToList();

        var request = context.HttpContext.Request;
        request.Body.Position = 0;

        using (var reader = new StreamReader(request.Body))
        {
            //get request body content
            var bodyString = reader.ReadToEnd();                

            //transfer content to json
            JObject json = JObject.Parse(bodyString);

            //if json contains fields that do not exist in Model, add model error                
            foreach (JProperty property in json.Children())
            {
                if (!listOfFieldNames.Contains(property.Name))
                {
                    context.ModelState.AddModelError("Filed", "Field does not exist");                      
                }
            }
        }
        base.OnActionExecuting(context);
    }
}
```

2.Use the filter on your action:

```
[HttpPost]
[CompareFieldsActionFilter]
public async  Task<ActionResult<Person>> Post([FromBody] PersonDto personDto)
{
   if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
       // do things
    }
  // do things
}
```