# Compare FromBody properties against Request model properties c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I working with a frontend team that won't respect API specification. for example, they use the response as a request and send a lot of properties that don't have a request model.

I want to check if a body request follows API specification and if a body request object is equal by structure with a specified request model.

For example, this is my method

```
public virtual IActionResult UpdateUser([FromRoute][Required]int? id, [FromBody]UserEditRequest body)
```

and on the very top of the method, I need to check the request format and if the body has extra properties that not exist in  UserEditRequest return error message and decline request.

I try check body.GetType().GetProperties() but this return properties of UserEditRequest, not of actual, received JSON request.

Compare and Equals not satisfy my requirements.

Any idea?

Comment: If you provide an API that consumes a body and you deserialize it into your class object, why do you bother if they send you more properties you don't need and which will immediately be dropped due to deserialization? You documented what you expect, but if they send more, simply don't bother (that's what I see, when I consume other 3rd party REST APIs).

Comment: If you really want to go that way, you have to implement your own [`IModelBinder`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/advanced/custom-model-binding?view=aspnetcore-5.0). This class is responsible to create the parameter objects given to the controller actions. So here you could read the query strings or the body stream and throw an error if something doesn't match your expectations or return the filled class for the controller action.

Comment: Hello @Oliver, thank you.
The main reason is to reduce traffic.

Comment: Hi @sasa, this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56441506/how-to-validate-for-illegal-fields-in-model-validation/56456050#56456050) may be helpful.

Comment: `Controller.Request.Form` (or `this.Request.Form` within an action method) is a simple way to access the body of the current request. You should be able to iterate over that if you're just looking for a short term hack. Otherwise a custom model binder is the way to go if you're planning on reusing it and keeping it in prod.